# Queries using temp tables

Tags: sql, temp-tables, sql-types

```
SELECT 1 
FROM geo_locationInfoMajor_tbl 
WHERE geo_locationInfoM_taluka IN(SELECT * from #temp
```

I have created a temp table which gets its values from the front end.. using a function I insert values into the temp table...
Now the data in the temp table is mixed... it can be integer or varchar..
when I pass only int or varchar into the temp table it is fine.
but if the output is mixed the query throws an error.. how to deal with this?
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'English' to data type int.

this is fine-->

```
#temp
1
```

this is not-->

```
1
English
```

Comment: What is the type of your `geo_locationInfoM_taluka` column?

Comment: varchar... but the same query is also used later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many values do you have in you temp table? 
if you want to use the IN clause you should only use one column that is identical with your geo_locationInfoMajor_tbl.

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM geo_locationInfoMajor_tbl 
WHERE geo_locationInfoM_taluka IN (SELECT geo_locationInfoM_taluka from #temp)
```

Comment: basically my temp table has more than 6 parmaters.. Integer and varchar. now if the value i am comparing with the temp table is inside the temp table then i need to return 1

Comment: IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM geo_locationInfo_tbl WHERE geo_locationInfo_value IN(SELECT * FROM #temp)))

Comment: so basically you want to check if your value exists in you temp table?

Comment: Yes i was getting stuck cause my temp table has oinly one column to hole both int and char values.. i used this  IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM geo_locationInfoMajor_tbl WHERE geo_locationInfoM_taluka IN(SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE ISNUMERIC(DataValues)<> 0))).. Its done now... thanks